# How to check if my model is empty outside of a Begin Form tag

Tags: c#, html, razor

Basically I have some hidden fields which cause an error when the data returned is empty. What I would like to do is to check if the model is empty and if it is empty, I'd like to skip the whole Begin Form tag and move onto my table. However, when I try this, it still stops and goes through the Begin Form tag. Is there anyway to change this?

You can see my setup below:

```
@if (!Model.ReportData.Any()) 
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("ReportSelection", "Reports", FormMethod.Post))      
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.StatusCategoryID, new SelectList(Model.StatusCategories, "StatusCategoryID", "StatusCategoryDesc"), "Select Status", new { @class = "GRDropDown", @id = "ReportDD" })
        <input type="hidden" name="StatusReportID" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ClientID" value="@Model.ReportData.Select(r => r.ClientID).FirstOrDefault()" />
        if (Model.ReportData.Select(r => r.SupplierID).Any()) 
        { 
            <input type="hidden" name="SupplierID" value="@Model.ReportData.Select(r => r.SupplierID).FirstOrDefault()" />
        }
        else if (Model.ReportData.Select(r => r.ReviewPeriodID).Any()) 
        { 
            <input type="hidden" name="ReviewPeriodID" value="@Model.ReportData.Select(r => r.ReviewPeriodID).FirstOrDefault()" />
        }
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    }
}
```

How can I stop it from executing the Begin form tag if the model is empty? I would have thought my IF would have stopped it but it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is backwards. You said "If it does NOT have anything in it, show this form":

```
@if (!Model.ReportData.Any()) {
```

You want it to be "If it has something in it, show this form":

```
@if (Model.ReportData.Any()) {
```

Comment: Cheers lad. Don't know how I didnt catch that one